# Inserting numeric data type using SQL statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, numeric, javadb

I am writing a method which allows users to store their data within my database.

The problem I have is storing a numeric datatype in my database, for a user's ID.

Firstly, how can I tell if the ID number is auto-incrementing? These are it's properties:

```
Type: Numeric
Column size: 4
Decimal digits: 0
Part of primary key: true
Part of an index: true
Position: 1
```

I'm sure I read somewhere that, setting it as part of an index (true) allows for auto-incrementation. Can anyone confirm?

More importantly, when inserting data into my table I receive an error stating:

```
Columns of type 'NUMERIC' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'.
```

This is a snippet of my insert code (I can reveal more if need be):

```
Statement pStatement = conn.createStatement();
String selectSQL = ("INSERT INTO APP.PERSON VALUES ('" + '3' + "','" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + fName + "','" + sName + "','" + sQuestion + "','" + sAnswer + "') ");
pStatement.executeUpdate(selectSQL);
```

As you can see I am setting ID (the first value), to 3 manually. I believe this is throwing up the error and would like to know how to insert a numeric value, using the INSERT command.

I am coding in Java, using Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2, on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I am using a Derby database.

Comment: Use placeholders: you'll thank me later. However, as the error message says, one of the columns contains an invalid value - will javadb convert `'3'` to `3`, for instance? I know SQL Server will, but .. also, to make life simpler, make sure to *include* the column names on an `INSERT`.

Comment: I will look into placeholders, thanks. I have another method doing the same thing in a different way and I believe I am using placeholders there - although I don't know what they are, I am assuming. My programming knowledge is not amazing! I should have mentioned, I tried "3" - '3' and 3. Neither of them work.

Comment: It might be a different column entirely - using column names, e.g. `INSERT INTO t (N1, N2) VALUES (V1, V2)` can help "clarify" which values are mapped to which columns. This clarification is further made/reinforced with [typed] placeholders so that the entire signature can be visually verified top (table) to bottom (Java) quickly.

Comment: Makes sense - I have more code to implement! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey bro I suggest u to use prepareStatement

```
String template = "INSERT INTO APP.PERSON VALUES (YOUR,TABLE,COLLUMN,NAME) values (?,?,?,?)";
           PreparedStatement stmt = yourConnection.prepareStatement(template);
```

So if your want to set your ID as an integer, let java do it with

```
       stmt.setInt(1, ID);
       stmt.setString(2, user);
       stmt.setString(3, fName);
       stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I dont know how is your table structure but this is an example if you want to use int 
use `stmt.setInt(1, 3);`

1--> position that u set up in string template

3--> maybe u want to hard coded the ID

here is my example pattern to use prepareStatement

```
String name = "shadrach"
Double price = "100.00"
int qty = 3;
    String template = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME,PRICE,QTY) values (?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(template);
                stmt.setString(1, name);
                stmt.setDouble(2, price);
                stmt.setInt(3, qty);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: In my other method I have wrote it exactly like this but without the 'VALUES (ID, NAME, AGE)' etc... 

Thanks a lot. All answers have helped - the problem isn't solved yet but I guess I have my work cut out. I don't know which answer to choose as the correct one - they all are!

Comment: Completely fixed now - works perfectly, thank you all. This helped the most so I selected it as the answer after editing it slightly due to there being a 'VALUE' after APP.PERSON which wasn't needed.

Comment: My pleasure to help u bro :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put single quotes around the number.  I'm not sure of the types of the other column data types but anything that is numeric should not contain the single quotes.

```
Statement pStatement = conn.createStatement();

String selectSQL = ("INSERT INTO APP.PERSON VALUES (3,'" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + fName + "','" + sName + "','" + sQuestion + "','" + sAnswer + "') ");

 pStatement.executeUpdate(selectSQL);
```

You should also look into switching this up to use a `PreparedStatement`, concatenating Strings to execute SQL will leave you vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.  Prepared statements will help mitigate this risk.

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same error using "3", perhaps it isn't a fault of my ID after all if this is definitely the correct way of inserting a numeric value. As you can see I called my Statement pStatement as it used to be a PreparedStatement but was having difficulties so changed it for now - I will change it back once finished.

Comment: Did you make sure you took out the single quote following the `(` and preceeding the `,`?

Comment: I literally copied your one line above (the middle one) - no luck, same error.

Comment: I saw your update and copied it over again and tried - same error again unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting the **character** 3 when the table expects a number.

You can tell if a column is auto-increment, using the [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)'s isAutoIncrement method. Hope that helps....